# replacing string in many many .php files

Tags: windows, editor

i have downloaded a website i have created and
want to find the domain name and replace it with a new one without having to open each file.

I use EditPlus

Is there any editor that can do this or do you know how to do this in windows or editplus?

thx

Comment: Well, at least you've learned not to hardcode the domain over and over again.

Comment: As @Kobi implies, it would be wise to replace the domain name with a variable.

Comment: normally i would use a variable but i never thought i would make an "exact" copy on a different domain

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). It has search and replace across one file, all open files, or all files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in powershell.

```
$textToRemove = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex "SOMEREGEX", SingleLine

Get-Item "*.php" | ForEach-Object {
    $backupfile = [System.IO.File]::Copy($_.FullName,"NEWPATH")
    $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)
    $text = $textToRemove.Replace($text, "REPLACEWITHTHIS")
    $newFile = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($_.FullName)
    $newFile.Write($text);
    $newFile.Close()
}
```

The above is untested code. Powershell is your friend for automating tasks like this.

Comment: If you're going to use the shell: perl -i -pe 's/word/replace/g' *.php

Comment: Sure, if he's got perl installed.  He said he's on a windows box.  And, if your going to use shell you can do this in sed in a more portable way doing `find . -type f -name *.php -print |xargs sed -i.BAK 's/word/replace/g'` and that will recurse into the dir structure.

Comment: find/xargs isn't exactly portable unless you have Cygwin installed. I mentioned Perl because it's just as likely to be installed as PowerShell, if not moreso.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, you could go for a trial version of something like Dreamweaver.

That said, I believe that [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is capable of this.

Answer (score 0):

I thought EditPlus has a "continue to the next file" button.

So Open all files 
press ctrl+F
find: olddomain
replace: newdomain

"Replace all"button and "continue to the next file" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Eclipse or Aptana to do this